# How to save a list of files names to CSV file in a FOR LOOP?

Tags: python, pandas, list, csv, for-loop

I have a CSV file with data (IDs) listed in one column and I added the extension to each ID via a for loop and then I would like to save the newly generated list in for loop to a CSV file. See the code.
[CSV file Data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12GvEnd4FyBlCzeE_Y5pwwA9UBQos_eeT/view?usp=sharing)

```
import pandas as pd

# list of extension for the EEG images
channels = ['_Ch_01', '_Ch_02', '_Ch_03', '_Ch_04', '_Ch_05', '_Ch_06', '_Ch_07', '_Ch_08', 
'_Ch_09', '_Ch_10', '_Ch_11', '_Ch_12', '_Ch_13', '_Ch_14', '_Ch_15', '_Ch_16', '_Ch_17', 
'_Ch_18', '_Ch_19']

# Restrive the ID of images 
df = pd.read_csv ("Data.csv")

# Select the EDF column and add an extension to each ID
for ext in channels:
    png = df['Data'].tolist()
    png_list = list(map(lambda orig_string: orig_string + ext + ".png", png))
    for files in png_list:
        if files.endswith(".png"):
        print(files)
        print(f"want to save all the {files} to csv file in one column")
```

Thanks!

Comment: tried `pd.to_csv()`?

Comment: Yes, I tried but it could not write the data to the CSV file in a column but only the last value in a loop.

Comment: There are 19 channels. Do you want 19 seperate CSVs or 1 CSV combining all channels as output?

Comment: @CodeDifferent 1 CSV combining as the out eg. 000254545_Ch_01, 000254545_Ch_02..... 000254545_CH_019 in one column of CSV file after looping through all the IDs from the CSV file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't even need looping for this:

```py
channels = [f"_Ch{i:02}.png" for i in range(1, 20)]

# Cross-product of df['Data'] and channels
# Essentially repeat each row in df['Data'] 19 times, once for each channel
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df['Data'], channels])

# Concatenate the two levels of the index and export
s = index.get_level_values(0) + index.get_level_values(1)
s.to_series().to_csv('Output.csv', index=None, header=None)
```